# Cannot make a LazyForeignCollection become eager collection

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm getting this error when trying to read a foreign collection from my POJO

```
AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal DAO
    object is null.  Lazy collections cannot be used if they have been deserialized.
```

The offending collection is `answers1` which i have marked as 'eager'

```
@ForeignCollectionField (eager=true)
private ForeignCollection<TextAnswer> answers1;
```

Why then when I debug the method below

```
public List<TextAnswer> getAnswers() {      
    return new ArrayList<TextAnswer>(answers1);
}
```

That it tells me the collection is a LazyForeignCollection?  I am puzzled.

I have no prob with this in any of my other classes that use ForeignCollections :(

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629985/ormlite-internal-dao-object-is-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lazy collections cannot be used if they have been deserialized.

Interesting problem.  First off, that message is *only* in the `LazyForeignCollection` class.  Is there any chance that the `answer1` field *used* to be lazy and was serialized?  Is serialization involved at all?  The `dao` field inside of a `ForeignCollection` should never be `null` unless the object has been serialized.

My assumption right now is that you are deserializing a previous version of the class.  If this is not the case then I have no idea.

Comment: Yes,  the field used to be lazy and I changed it to eager. Is that what you mean?

Comment: And are you loading in some data from disk or something that is old @user965895?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  The object is taken out of a Bundle and it will have been serialized in order to put into the Bundle.

Comment: Not sure what a `Bundle` is.  If it is being deserialized then you will have to re-serialize it.

Comment: @Gray How does one change a field from Lazy to Eager? Presumably, changing the annotations between runs of the app won't cause this issue... right? - Ah, the field is being serialized and persisted in a `Bundle` and then deserialized.