# ORMLite : Internal DAO object is null

Tags: java, android, foreign-key-relationship, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite, trying to use the ForeignCollectionKey but I got the following error :

> Internal DAO object is null. LazyCollections cannot be used if they have been deserialized.

I've my object named Zone :

```
public class Zone implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String ZONE_ID = "id"; 
    public static final String ZONE_PARENT_ID = "parentZoneId";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField()
    String name;
    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    Zone parentZone;

    @ForeignCollectionField(foreignFieldName = "parentZone", eager = true)
    private ForeignCollection<Zone> zoneChild;

    public Zone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public ForeignCollection<Zone> getZoneChild() {
        return zoneChild;
    }
    public void setZoneChild(ForeignCollection<Zone> zoneChild) {
        this.zoneChild = zoneChild;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

In a class i'm doing a recursive method to get all my zone child objects :

```
public void getZone(Zone zone, Dao<Zone, Integer> tempZoneDao){
    ZoneListEntity zoneEntity = new ZoneListEntity();
    zoneEntity.setName(zone.getName());
    zoneEntity.setNiveau(0);
    zoneEntity.setZone(zone);
    mainZoneList.add(zoneEntity);

    List<Zone> childList = new ArrayList<Zone>(zone.getZoneChild());
    //set rootZone's children as ZoneListEntity
    for(Zone currentZone : childList){
        ZoneListEntity zoneGroup = new ZoneListEntity();
        zoneGroup.setName(currentZone.getName());
        zoneGroup.setZone(currentZone);
        System.out.println("Zone : "+currentZone.getName());
        getZone(currentZone, tempZoneDao);
    }
}
```

When i'm entering for the first time in my `getZone`, everything going well. Then when I loop in `getZone` the application crashes trying to access to the child zone :

```
List<Zone> childList = new ArrayList<Zone>(zone.getZoneChild());
```

Do you have any ideas ? Is my model construction right ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have any ideas ? Is my model construction right ? Thanks

So the exception message is trying to explain what is going on.  I'm not sure how it can be improved.

> Internal DAO object is null. LazyCollections cannot be used if they have been deserialized.

You are trying to access `zoneChild` which is a `ForeignCollection` that has been deserialized.  Since it has been deserialized all of the underlying database configurations and connections could not be reestablished.  I guess this can happen when it stored in an Android `Bundle`?  I'm not sure if this is the only case.

If you need to get the `Zone` children you are going to have to either call `dao.refresh()` on the entity *after* you deserialize it or do the query yourself by doing the `zoneDao`.

Comment: already tried the refresh but not working... I changed my database model it works better but without self relationship.

Comment: Does this question help @Max?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802976/how-can-i-fill-the-foreign-collection-manually/20907285#20907285

Comment: Calling refresh *does* actually work, call it on the object which you got the foreignCollection from, the object which you've sent through the Extras

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like Gray suggested: pass the primary key attribute in the Bundle and then obtain the object again from the database in the destination Activity:

Example:

Let's suppose I want to pass a Person object and that I've declared `Person.name` as:

```
@DatabaseField (columnName ="name")
private String name;
```

Then:

**ActivityA**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("NAME" Person.getName());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**ActivityB**

```
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME"));
Person p = getHelper().getPersonDao().queryForEq("name", name);
```

And there you are, your Collection will be refreshed.