# How can I fill the foreign collection manually

Tags: java, android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
private ForeignCollection<Field> fieldCollection;
```

and I want to fill this collection from data coming from web service because I want to insert this data to my Sqlite database.

I tried to use this:

```
boolean accessOnPremiseDb = false;
String description;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
private ForeignCollection<Entity> entitiyCollection =
     new LazyForeignCollection<Entity, Integer>(null, accessOnPremiseDb, 
          accessOnPremiseDb, null, description, accessOnPremiseDb);
```

but I got the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal DAO object is null.
   Lazy collections cannot be used if they have been deserialized.
```

How can I do that without problem?  Should I make new variable for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... I want to fill this collection from data coming from web service because I want to insert this data to my Sqlite database.

Right.  The serialization error message is misleading.  You are trying to create a foreign collection and you can't call the constructor directly.  You should instead be calling

```
dao.assignEmptyForeignCollection(data, "entitiyCollection");
```

or

```
data.entitiyCollection = dao.getEmptyForeignCollection("entitiyCollection");
```

This wires the appropriate DAO object into the foreign collection.  I've improved the javadocs and the error message.

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/b4037999c21f45c426ce7a83bc759e3ec8335c61

Comment: if I use Collection<Entity>  instead of  ForeignCollection<Entity> and filled the data using ArrayList, could I have any problems  ?

Comment: Is there a mass-create for this? I'm confused about how the data ends up getting inserted...