# Lazy collections cannot be used if they have been deserialized

Tags: android, database, ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm using ORM Lite in my project, and I have a situation where step by putExtra the intent of a Person object, which has a Collection of Email object, but when I try to read this Collection which is like LazyLoad (eager = false) below follows the models and the code used to retrieve the collection of Email:

```
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

        ...

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager=false)
    private Collection<Email> emails;

        ...
}
public class Email implements Serializable{

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

    ...

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private Pessoa pessoa;

       ...
}
```

Retrieving the Collection:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("Pessoa")){
       pessoa = (Pessoa) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Pessoa");

Iterator<Endereco> iterator = pessoa.getEnderecos().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Endereco end = iterator.next();
        Log.e("ENDERECO",end.getLogradouro());
}
```

I get the following error:

> 12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.pedidosexample/com.example.abertura.CadastroVisualizacao}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal DAO object is null.  Lazy
>   collections cannot be used if they have been deserialized. 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-18 11:48:08.168:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-18 11:48:08.168:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-18 11:48:08.168:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26028): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Internal DAO object is null.  Lazy collections cannot be used if they
>   have been deserialized. 12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):
>     at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.seperateIteratorThrow(LazyForeignCollection.java:310)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iteratorThrow(LazyForeignCollection.java:71)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.closeableIterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:60)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:47)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.LazyForeignCollection.iterator(LazyForeignCollection.java:28)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.example.abertura.CadastroVisualizacao.preencheCampos(CadastroVisualizacao.java:85)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   com.example.abertura.CadastroVisualizacao.onCreate(CadastroVisualizacao.java:53)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470) 12-18
>   11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   12-18 11:48:08.168: E/AndroidRuntime(26028):  ... 11 more

The error clearly says what the problem is, but it has another way to pass the Person object to another intent and that works with lite ORM?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629985/ormlite-internal-dao-object-is-null

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224324/cannot-make-a-lazyforeigncollection-become-eager-collection?lq=1

Comment: Okay, I looked at the links you sent me, but I know when a serialized LazyCollection is I can not retrieve their values​​, but wanted to know a way to pass to another view without using Serializable, has an example?

Answer (score -2):

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)

Comment: where? what? any explanation?